# What environment is more portable QT or java and which do you suggest using for my application needs?

Tags: java, qt, portability

I want to wrap a website and create an application around it (kind of like the iPhone/iPod Facebook app) and i want the application to be as portable as possible so with a very few modification to the code it can run on pc, mac, iPod, android or any other.
I know that Java is known for it's portability but i dislike it and i don't know about QT.

I know this question is quite subjective but can you give me a couple of opinions and reasons for them any way?

Thanks in advance,
Dante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is portable enough for the major platforms (Windows, Linux and MacOS). It has the advantage of being native code, so no virtual machine is needed. And it provides rich graphics and other powerfull features, and the GUI look and feel of the specific platform.

If you are considering the same code base to be shared between desktop and mobile platforms, think again. There are different constraints in terms of resources, screen dimensions, etc. Qt can be used for some mobile platforms (mainly Symbian, Maemoo), Java for Android and ObjectiveC/C++ for iPhone/iPod. So a cross mobile platform application using the same technology is not feasible (at least for the moment).